# Why Not returning value after AddDomainEvent in CQRS pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, .net-6.0, cqrs, mediatr

I use CQRS pattern with MediatR in my project.In 2 parts, it doesn't end the way I expect.

1: When I want to return a value after changes with a command,I save the changes by using (for example: usermanager), that's why the created view model is no longer returned and it is sent to the event push path.

BaseEntity :

```
public abstract class BaseEntity : IBaseId<string>, IEntityWithDomainEvent
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    private readonly List<BaseEvent> _domainEvents = new();

    [NotMapped]
    public IReadOnlyCollection<BaseEvent> DomainEvents => _domainEvents.AsReadOnly();

    public void AddDomainEvent(BaseEvent domainEvent)
    {
        _domainEvents.Add(domainEvent);
    }

    public void RemoveDomainEvent(BaseEvent domainEvent)
    {
        _domainEvents.Remove(domainEvent);
    }

    public void ClearDomainEvents()
    {
        _domainEvents.Clear();
    }
    
}
```

```
public class LoginUserCommand : IRequest<ResponseLoginViewModel>
{
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string VerifyCode { get; set; }
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
}

public class LoginUserCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<LoginUserCommand, ResponseLoginViewModel>
{
    private readonly IIdentityService _identityService;

    public LoginUserCommandHandler(IIdentityService identityService)
    {
        _identityService = identityService;
    }
    public async Task<ResponseLoginViewModel> Handle(LoginUserCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var user = await _identityService.GetUserWithMobileAsync(request.PhoneNumber);
        if (user.VerifyCode == request.VerifyCode)
        {

            var res = await _identityService.LoginUser(user);

            user.RefreshToken = res.RefreshToken;
            user.RefreshTokenExpiryTime = res.Expiration;

            user.AddDomainEvent(new DriverLoggedInEvent(user));

            user.VerifyCode = await _identityService.GenerateRandomCode();

//TODO: Here If I use _usermanager.updateuser it no longer returns to (return res) and 
 goes to the DriverLoggedInEventHandler class 

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(res.Token))
            {
                return new ResponseLoginViewModel();
            }
            return res;
        }
        return new ResponseLoginViewModel();
    }
}
```

2: My َApplicationUser class inherits both from IdentityUser and from the interface I created called: IEntityWithDomainEvent.

```
public interface IEntityWithDomainEvent
{
    IReadOnlyCollection<BaseEvent> DomainEvents { get; }
    void AddDomainEvent(BaseEvent domainEvent);
    void RemoveDomainEvent(BaseEvent domainEvent);
    void ClearDomainEvents();
}
```

But I can't put .Entries() at the time of savechange, so I've passed it in the stupidest way for now.

```
public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            try
            {
                await _mediator.DispatchDomainEvents(this);

                return await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                throw new Exception(e.Message);
            }
         
        }
```

DispatchDomainEvent:

```
public static class MediatorExtensions
{
    public static async Task DispatchDomainEvents(this IMediator mediator, DbContext context)
    {
        var entities = context.ChangeTracker
           .Entries<BaseEntity>()
           .Where(e => e.Entity.DomainEvents.Any())
           .Select(e => e.Entity);

        var domainEvents = entities
           .SelectMany(e => e.DomainEvents)
           .ToList();
        entities.ToList().ForEach(e => e.ClearDomainEvents());

        // TODO : Problem two is solved for now by the following silly method

        if (domainEvents.Count == 0)
        {
            var entities2 = context.ChangeTracker
               .Entries<ApplicationUser>()
               .Where(e => e.Entity.DomainEvents.Any())
               .Select(e => e.Entity);

            domainEvents = entities2
                .SelectMany(e => e.DomainEvents)
                .ToList();
            entities2.ToList().ForEach(e => e.ClearDomainEvents());
        }


        foreach (var domainEvent in domainEvents)
            await mediator.Publish(domainEvent);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Update1:
In LoginUserCommandHandler: Please read the TODO section. The problem is in the DispatchDomainEvent section in the TODO section.
After update user with _usermanager.updateuser in LoginUserCommandHandler, because the database is saved, that's why the value of return res in LoginUserCommandHandler is not returned

Comment: TBH not following what exactly is the problem. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: The question has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what actual problems are but as for `DispatchDomainEvents` it seems that `BaseEntity` should implement `IEntityWithDomainEvent` and if it does - you can just use the interface simplifying the implementation:

```cs
public static async Task DispatchDomainEvents(this IMediator mediator, DbContext context)
{
    var entities = context.ChangeTracker
        .Entries<IEntityWithDomainEvent>()
        .Where(e => e.Entity.DomainEvents.Any())
        .Select(e => e.Entity);

    var domainEvents = entities
        .SelectMany(e => e.DomainEvents)
        .ToList();
    entities.ToList().ForEach(e => e.ClearDomainEvents());
    
    foreach (var domainEvent in domainEvents)
        await mediator.Publish(domainEvent);
}
```

Also possibly double enumeration of `entities` is not ideal, so:

```cs
public static async Task DispatchDomainEvents(this IMediator mediator, DbContext context)
{
    var entities = context.ChangeTracker
        .Entries<IEntityWithDomainEvent>()
        .Where(e => e.Entity.DomainEvents.Any())
        .Select(e => e.Entity);

    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        foreach (var domainEvent in entity.DomainEvents)
        {
            await mediator.Publish(domainEvent);
        }

        entity.ClearDomainEvents();
    }
}
```

Comment: problem 2 :If I use updateUser, because I have used .Entries<BaseEntity>() in DispatchDomainEvents, the existing EventHandlers for the applicationuser class cannot be pushed. problem 1: I have updated in the last part and update.